# Do Necrons have (or had) priests?

Tags: warhammer-40k, xenos

The universe of Warhammer 40000 is very spiritual<sup>1</sup> - gods (or god-like beings) are very real and widely worshipped: the biggest political organization - the Imperium of Man - is in fact a theocracy, with various political and military figures justifying their action as "the will of God-Emperor".

The Necrons culture is based mostly on real-life Ancient Egypt, with a hints of other pyramid-building cultures like Mesopotamia, Mayans or Aztec <sup>2</sup> - all those cultures had a highly organized religions and the priesthood had high status in the structure of the communities.

We know, that the C'tan were worshipped as gods by the ancient Necrontyr but was this continued when they've became immortal Necrons? Has the priesthood survived the rebellion and the [Great Sleep](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Great_Sleep)?

<sup>1 The Tau and Dark Eldars are a bit of exception, but the former worship "The Greater Good" and the Ehtereal caste is a priesthood in all but name. Dark Eldars on the other hand refuse to believe in anything out of spite</sup>

<sup>2 In case of [Trazyn the Infinite](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Trazyn) it would be rather something like Las Vegas.</sup>

Comment: Some Dark Eldar are trying to awaken Ynnead, if that counts as believing in something.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are three parts to this:

1. Necrontyr before they met the C'Tan
2. Necrontyr under C'Tan rule
3. Necrons

## Necrontyr before meeting the C'Tan

From the  [article on C'Tan in Lexicanum](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/C%27tan)

> While the Necrontyr, Mephet'ran was known as the Messenger, amongst its own kind it was known as the Deceiver. With honeyed words, the Deceiver spoke of an ancient war between the Old Ones and the C'tan long before the birth of Necrontyr, a war the C'tan lost. The Deceiver and its brethren hid themselves away from the vengeance of the Old Ones and the C'tan bided their time until they could find allies against the Old Ones. To that end, the Deceiver offered the Triarch council two things the Necrontyr desperately sought: unity and immortality, which would be implemented in the form of biotransference. For one year since the Deceiver's proposition the Triarch and the nobles of the Royal Court debated the matter with Orikan, the court astrologer, being the only dissenting voice. Regardless of the dissent, the Triarch ultimately agreed to the Deceiver's offer.

What we can learn from that:

- There was a court astrologer, i.e. astrology was held in high respect within the Necrontyr society.

From the [astrology article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrology) (emphasis by me):

> **Astrology is a pseudoscience** that claims to divine information about human affairs and terrestrial events by studying the movements and relative positions of celestial objects.

So, we nowadays consider astrology not a science but more kind of a religion. With the Necrontyr being a non-psycic race, astrology has no more power of divination than guessing and experiencing. They still had made use of it, implicating that they believed in the supernatural and priests (maybe only in the form of astrologers) existed in this society.

## Necrontyr under the rule of the C'Tan

From the [article on Necrontyrs on Lexicanum](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Necrontyr):

> The first being to come across the starlight bridge was Aza'gorod, the Night Bringer. As the creature became more manifest and intelligent, the Necrontyr began to worship the C'tan as gods for their supreme power. The C'tan turned the Necrontyr into slaves and enjoyed ruling over them with cruelty and disgust.

So, the Necrontyr worshiped the C'Tan as gods. I think it is reasonable to assume that something worshipped has priests. Maybe those priests were different from what we would think of them as their gods were real. They might've been more like the ones communicating the desires of the C'Tan to the Necrontyr and vice-versa (see first quote that they discussed terms to become immortal).

## Necrons

Looking at the Necron units list [here](http://home-2002.code-cop.org/40k/necron.html), I cannot find any unit named priests or something similar, compared to the units of the Adeptus Ministorum found [here](http://home-2002.code-cop.org/40k/imperial.html#church). It is also important to note that the average Necron is more akin to a servitor than a human. The only concious Necrons that remain are the Overlords and the Silent King himself. However, they've turned upon the C'Tan and will certainly not worship them anymore.

Answer (score 2):

### Necrons dropped all pretense of worship after the War in Heaven

After their bio-transference, almost all Necrons became subservient to their overlords, completely unthinking and lacking any free will to worship either the overlords or a greater power. They are all controlled by command protocols. Even the lesser lords are only subservient due to their own command protocols.

This hierarchy may mimic ancient earth cultures that did worship gods, but that's where the resemblance ends.

With the the Silent King's machinations to trap the C'Tan in the Tesseract Labyrinths there is no longer anything for the free thinking necrons to worship, not that they would want to after the C'Tan betrayed the Necrontyr.

Essentially all free thinking Necron's realise this betrayal, which is why they as a whole turned against the C'Tan.

I've not heard or read of any rogue factions of necros that still worship the C'Tan or any other beings.

Nor did they seem to have priests as Necrontyr, because the god*like* C'Tan could physically manifest, there was no need for an intermediary priest class.

So there is no reason for Necron Priests, or anything analogous, to exist. All of their power structures are non-religious.